# count the number of negatives in an array using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, count

I have written a code which counts negative numbers in an array and now need to write the same code using the recursion technique. I am new to recursion so I'm not sure if i am on the right track with this code.

```
public int countNeg (int[ ] nums, int n)
{
    int neg = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < n; index ++)
        if (nums[index] < 0)
            neg++;
    return neg;
}
```

for the recursive code, this is what i did:

```
public int countNeg (int[ ] nums, int n)
{
     if (n < 0)
         return 0;
     else {
         int neg = countNeg (nums, n-1);
         if (nums[n-1] < 0)
             return neg + 1;
         else
             return neg;
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it?  Are you getting any errors?  Is it not working?  (it looks like it should work, except for when n=0)

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @mureinik this is my first time using the recursion technique and i wasn't sure if my code was correct and doing the task of counting negative numbers in an array

Comment: @PrincessTashi easiest way to check is to test it.  I pasted it into a [java tester](https://www.compilejava.net/) and it immediately told me I was correct that `if(n < 0)` will cause an out of bounds exception.  Changed it to `if(n <= 0)` and it worked

Comment: @phflack oh right i see, that makes sense. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 1):

n is the parameter which is index.
You can use the method below:

```
int numberOfNegativeNumbers = countNeg(nums, 0);
```

Method:

```
public int countNeg (int[ ] nums, int n) {
  if(n >= nums.length)
    return 0;
  else
    return ((mums[n] < 0) ? 1 : 0) + countNeg(nums, n+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bilghen's answer already provides the required solution.

I will however offer a solution which uses [Tail Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) technique.

```
public int countNeg (int[ ] nums, int index) {
  return countNegTailRecur(nums, index, 0);
}

public int countNegTailRecur (int[ ] nums, int index, int total) {
  if(index >= nums.length)
    return total;
  else
    return countNeg(nums, index+1, nums[index] < 0 ? total + 1 : total);
}
```

Call it like so -

```
int numberOfNegativeNumbers = countNeg(nums, 0);
```